# Difference between foundation reveal modal and foundation regular modal

Tags: modal-dialog, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5, zurb-foundation-apps

What is the difference between [foundation reveal modal](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/reveal.html) and a [regular foundation modal](http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/docs/#!/modal)? Are they optimized for different things? I tried to read about them, but didn't find any reference. Why do they have 2 different modals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made some digging, and apparently the regular is for "foundation for apps", and the reveal is for foundation desktop (or like 5.x something).